# jQuery Mobile and MVC3 auto submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

The following code works perfectly if I take jQuery Mobile out of the question!

**The form:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchTown", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm1" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("TownID", (SelectList)ViewBag.TownId, "Select a Town")
}
```

**The Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#TownID").live('change', function () {
            //$("#TownID").change(function () {
            var actionUrl = $('#TheForm1').attr('action') + '/' + $('#TownID').val();
            $('#TheForm1').attr('action', actionUrl);
            $('#TheForm1').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But if I wrap jQuery Mobile around the site, then every time I submit the form, in my log only it tacks the ID field again and again to the end of the URL string. This only happens in my log, not in the browser. In the browser it still **looks** like it’s doing the right thing! E.g..

**www.mysite.com/Home/SearchTown/2** the first time

**www.mysite.com/Home/SearchTown/2/2** the second time

**www.mysite.com/Home/SearchTown/2/2/2** the third time

But in the browser it still looks correct www.mysite.com/Home/SearchTown/2

Why is jQuery Mobile doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv'e left this one up long enough and no one has an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because each time you POST the form, it uses AJAX to load the response and the loaded page has repeated element IDs in it.

I'm guessing here, but based on what you described it sounds like your form posts back to a page with the same form markup on it. Each time your form post renders the next page you'll get *another* `#TheForm1` added to your DOM (as jQuery Mobile keeps previously loaded pages in the DOM and simply swaps between active `data-role="page"` elements). Due to this behavior, once you have more than one `#TheForm1` on the page, the selector `$('#TheForm')` will only ever return the first element in the DOM matching that ID- which will be the form which you posted the very first time. Thus, each time you you post, your code will use the action attribute of the form element you modified originally- which is why you see multiple values appended to the URL.

In jQuery Mobile it is almost always better to identify elements using a class name and the active page as the container, as you never know how many times an ID might be repeated in the DOM across multiple page changes. So, instead of using `$('#TheForm1')`, assign a class name and use that in conjunction with `$.mobile.activePage`: `$('.Form1', $.mobile.activePage)`. (The same goes for your select box).

As an alternative, you can tell jQuery Mobile to not enhance your form by adding `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag. This will cause it to behave like a normal full page postback without any AJAX.

**Edit**

The point I am making in paragraph 3 is that you need to make sure you're always selecting the correct form element for the currently visible page, rather than unintentionally returning one which is hidden from view. The `$.mobile.activePage` global variable will give you the context of the currently visible page, and then a class-based selector (rather than Id-based) will ensure that the correct form element is retrieved in the change handler. Something like this:

```
<form class="town-form" action="#">
    <select class="town-selector">
        <option value="1">Town A</option>
        <option value="2">Town B</option>
        <option value="3">Town C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".town-selector").live('change', function () {
            var form = $('.town-form', $.mobile.activePage);
            var actionUrl = form.attr('action') + '/' + $(this).val();
            form.attr('action', actionUrl);
            alert('submitting to: ' + form.attr('action'));
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I understand what is happening re the DOM but can you show me an example of what you are saying in the third paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

because you are submitting the hole page and jQuery mobile does not fancy such thing, and after each `POST` it just appends the ID into the `document.location`... I have learned that in some mobile projects...

instead of this line `$('#TheForm1').submit();` do something like this:

```
var url = $('#TheForm1').attr('action') + '/' + $('#TownID').val();

$.post(url, $('#TheForm1').serialize(), function(data) {
    // do something with data if you send back something...
    // or just change page with jQuery Mobile API
});

return false;
```